# How to change effect texture when effect is expiring?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs, minecraft-optifine

I'm working on a texture pack using Optifine's CIT method. Is there any way to change the effect's icon texture when its remaining time is below 2 seconds?